# Get what's behind "Location:" with XPath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I try to get **France** that's behind Location:

I wrote this XPath: `//div[@class="vevent"]/div/div/span[text()="Location: "]`. That's how far I came, but how to I get France that comes after.

```
<div class="vevent">
    <div style="float:left; padding-right: 20px;"><img alt="I’M YOUR DJ New Year Edition / 5th Anniversary Celebration" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/latindancecalendar/image/fetch/w_350,h_350/https%3A%2F%2Fi1.wp.com%2Flatindancecalendar.com%2Fdancecal%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F50015933_2182298412088647_1361353647551676416_o.jpg%3Fresize%3D350%252C350%26ssl%3D1" width="200" height="200" scale="0"></div>
    <div style="float:left;"><span class="dtstart"><span class="value-title" title="2019-12-27"></span></span><span><b>Friday, 27 December 2019</b></span>
        <div><span class="location">Château Lafitte Yvrac ( Bordeaux ) - SCEA Chateau LAFITTE 41 Chemin du Loup, 33370 Yvrac, Aquitaine, France</span></div>
        <div>Hosted by <b><a href="https://latindancecalendar.com/im-your-dj-new-year-edition-bordeaux/">I’M YOUR DJ – New Year Edition – Bordeaux</a></b></div>
        <div><span>Location: </span>France</div>
        <div><span class="eventpostviews"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=Ch%C3%A2teau+Lafitte+Yvrac+%28+Bordeaux+%29+-+SCEA+Chateau+LAFITTE+41+Chemin+du+Loup%2C+33370+Yvrac%2C+Aquitaine%2C+France" class="map_link" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>Map</a> | 175 Views | <a style="color:#8F8F8F;" href="https://latindancecalendar.com/report-a-listing/?listing-url=https%3A%2F%2Flatindancecalendar.com%2Ffestivals%2Fim-your-dj-new-year-edition-5th-anniversary-celebration-2019%2F" rel="nofollow"><i class="fas fa-times" style="padding-right: 3px;font-size: 11px;"></i>Report Problem</a></span></div>
        <div style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Flatindancecalendar.com%2Ffestivals%2Fim-your-dj-new-year-edition-5th-anniversary-celebration-2019%2F&amp;width&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;size=large&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=false&amp;height=35&amp;appId=532405580227185" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:35px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: I added the HTML instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
//div[@class="vevent"]/div/div[span = "Location: "]/text()
```

It selects the `div` that contains a `span` with the string value `"Location: "` and then retrieves the text node directly within that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Better give the html in script. Not picture.
And I guess you can use:
'''
following::text()
'''

Comment: The picture was replaced with HTML 6 minutes before you posted your answer.